# When the if condition is true it still prints else condition statement

Tags: javascript, if

Hope guys are doing well.

I'm a newb and still learning javascript.

My if condition isn't working, I created a simple if-else loop (if any condition is met it should print following conditions statement). I tried googling but couldn't found my answer.

The condition should work as, if the user doesn't enter first name it shouldn't print anything, when I'm trying to enter first name, the first name field is replaced with `null` and when the if condition is true it still prints else condition statement.

Below is my JS code.

```
if (this.firstName === null) {
    console.log('Please enter first name' + typeof(this.firstName));
} else {
    console.log('Contact Created is First name & Last name.');
}
```

I tried with `=`,`==`and`===`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I couldn't understand your question, but I think you want something like this

```
console.log(this.firstName, typeof this.firstName)
if (!this.firstName) {
    console.log('Please enter first name' + typeof(this.firstName));
} else {
    console.log('Contact Created is First name & Last name.');
}
```

It'll show `please enter first name` if you don't specify the name. Because empty input has the value of `''` and when it gets converted to `Boolean` it's `false`

Comment: It is still printing the else statement mate.

Comment: updated the code, added additional console.log, now you should know what is the actual value and you can debug the issue

Comment: Thank you mate for your time.

Comment: Np, glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

This then necessarily means that the value that is being returned is not the null literal instead that could be undefined or something else. You may print the firstname on console and determine what you are getting. If you are getting null is it a literal null or a string null?

This syntax help you

```
if (this.firstName === undefined || this.firstName == null || this.firstName.length <= 0)
```

Comment: It is still printing the else statement bhai.

Comment: What is console output for this.firstName??

Comment: `Please enter first name` basically it's a hardcoded message.

Comment: i mean what is the output for consloe.log(this.firstName)? And can you also let us know your code for this object and its initialization?